# Qt programming error

Tags: qt, projects

I am developing Qt project. Previously I developed complete project that access database, but due to some reason i formatted the disk. When later on i run the project it showed me error for using QSqlDatabase QSqlError classes.
Please help me.

Comment: have you reinstalled the Qt libraries?

Comment: Please post some error messages so we can better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something is missing in your [Qmake](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qmake-variable-reference.html#config) project.